# Error when try to upload an .ipa file to saucelabs

Tags: saucelabs

Hellow! I am using curl to upload an ios file to SauceLabs.com but get this error in terminal.
Any idea?

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
```

Comment: Better to contact Sauce Labs support for this instead of using SO

Comment: Yep, thanks man! I did it, just that looks takes long time to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

Without verbose logs to look at, there's two reasons this might be happening:

1. You're trying to connect to the REST API on port 80 instead of port 443, either explicitly or because you're using http instead of https.
2. Your network is blocking the connection.

Generally, if you run curl with the `-v` argument, it'll give you more details about what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is solved and was because some of this reasons. Thanks